# Simple ISO date, time and datetime implementation

Tags: beginner, datetime, reinventing-the-wheel, rust

I am getting started with rust. To get familiar with the language I implemented a datetime library:
`main.rs`

```rust
mod datetime;
use datetime::DateTime;
use datetime::Date;
use datetime::Time;


fn main() {
    let date_time = DateTime::create(2022u16, 09, 17, 02, 53, 00);
    println!("Datetime: {}", date_time);
    println!("Date: {}", date_time.date);
    println!("Time: {}", date_time.time);
    let date = Date::new(2022u16, 09, 17);
    println!("Date: {}", date);
    let time = Time::new(03, 51, 00);
    println!("Time: {}", time);
}
```

`datetime.rs`

```rust
use std::fmt;

mod date;
pub use self::date::Date;

mod time;
pub use self::time::Time;


pub struct DateTime {
    pub date: Date,
    pub time: Time
}


impl DateTime {
    pub fn new(date: impl Into<Date>, time: impl Into<Time>) -> DateTime {
        DateTime { date: date.into(), time: time.into() }
    }

    pub fn create(
            year: impl Into<u16>,
            month: impl Into<u8>,
            day: impl Into<u8>,
            hour: impl Into<u8>,
            minute: impl Into<u8>,
            second: impl Into<u8>
    ) -> DateTime {
        DateTime::new(Date::new(year, month, day), Time::new(hour, minute, second))
    }

    pub fn isoformat(&self) -> String {
        format!("{}T{}", self.date.isoformat(), self.time.isoformat())
    }
}

impl fmt::Display for DateTime {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "{}", self.isoformat())
    }
}
```

`datetime/date.rs`

```rust
use std::fmt;


pub struct Date {
    pub year: u16,
    pub month: u8,
    pub day: u8
}


impl Date {
    pub fn new(year: impl Into<u16>, month: impl Into<u8>, day: impl Into<u8>) -> Date {
        Date { year: year.into(), month: month.into(), day: day.into() }
    }

    pub fn isoformat(&self) -> String {
        format!("{:0>4}-{:0>2}-{:0>2}", self.year, self.month, self.day)
    }
}

impl fmt::Display for Date {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "{}", self.isoformat())
    }
}
```

`datetime/time.rs`

```rust
use std::fmt;


pub struct Time {
    pub hour: u8,
    pub minute: u8,
    pub second: u8
}


impl Time {
    pub fn new(hour: impl Into<u8>, minute: impl Into<u8>, second: impl Into<u8>) -> Time {
        Time { hour: hour.into(), minute: minute.into(), second: second.into() }
    }

    pub fn isoformat(&self) -> String {
        format!("{:0>2}:{:0>2}:{:0>2}", self.hour, self.minute, self.second)
    }
}

impl fmt::Display for Time {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "{}", self.isoformat())
    }
}
```

Since I'm completely new to rust, I'd like to have feedback on code style and proper use of language concepts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

welcome to the Rust community!

Your code is quite good. There are a couple areas where the code could be improved, but not by much. It would be helpful if you implement more code for review all at once, for example datetime parsing code.

### `DateTime::create`

```rust
pub fn create(
        year: impl Into<u16>,
        month: impl Into<u8>,
        day: impl Into<u8>,
        hour: impl Into<u8>,
        minute: impl Into<u8>,
        second: impl Into<u8>
)
```

The function name is not descriptive. It is idiomatic to name constructors e.g. `with_date_and_time`.

I do not like that your arguments are `impl Into<u16>` or `impl Into<u8>`. Why is it better to accept precisely `u16` or `u8` here? See the following error to figure out why. Very little convenience is lost -- the caller can do `.into()` if needed.

```rust
// error[E0283]: type annotations needed
//     --> src/main.rs:17:16
//     |
// 17 |     let time = Time::new("03".parse().unwrap(), "51".parse().unwrap(), "00".parse().unwrap());
//     |                ^^^^^^^^^ cannot infer type for type parameter `impl Into<u8>` declared on the associated function `new`
//     |
//     = note: cannot satisfy `_: Into<u8>`
// note: required by a bound in `Time::new`
let time = Time::new("03".parse().unwrap(), "51".parse().unwrap(), "00".parse().unwrap());
println!("Time: {}", time);
```

Basically, `impl Trait` in argument position does not inform type inference. Some functions such as `str::parse` return generic results parameterized by a free parameter, so it may be best to guide inference.

Accepting `impl Trait` in argument position is usually unidiomatic.

Furthermore, `impl Into<u16>` is why you have to write `2022u16` and can't write just `2022`.

So we have:

```rust
pub fn with_date_and_time(
        year: u16,
        month: u8,
        day: u8,
        hour: u8,
        minute: u8,
        second: u8
)
```

### public fields

My recommendation is to add accessor methods and make fields private.

If you want to change inner representation someday, you wouldn't need to break backwards compatibility. This is important in library code. But in binary code, you may change representation without breaking other modules, so this is beneficial as well.

```rust
pub struct Time {
    hour: u8,
    minute: u8,
    second: u8
}

impl Time {
    fn hour(&self) -> u8 {
        self.hour
    }

    // ..
}
```

### `isoformat`

I recommend a better method name such as `to_iso_format` or `to_rfc3339`. The name `to_rfc3339` is consistent with chrono's DateTime.

### more

Your code is not formatted with rustfmt. I recommend `cargo fmt`.

For lints, I recommend `cargo clippy`.

### github

https://github.com/pczarn/codereview/tree/7a1952ec0bf9c5c813802becff27785ed57178de/2022/9/datetime

### edit

Your `impl Display` allocates a String twice. It is better to implement `isoformat` that calls `self.to_string()` rather than the other way around.

### derive `Debug`

Most library users expect types to implement Debug.